# I need to be able to query attendence style data referencing youth from one table, an event "type" from another table, on a specific date

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a database that would organize members for a club.

I'm looking at being able to keep data on each member, the kinds of events we have, and the events that occur.

I would like to be able to tell what members attended what event on a specific date and this is where i'm stuck. I can't think of a way to store the information so that when I need to I can query a list of all the members (memberName) that attended on this date (attendenceDate) as well as tell what kind of event (eventType) they attended.

This is the basics of what I have, feel free to offer constructive criticism.

```
tblMember
*memberID
memberName

tblEvent
*eventID
eventType

tblAttendance
*attendenceID (This specifies the individual event)
attendanceDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
tblMember
memberID
memberName

tblEvent
eventID
eventType
eventDate

tblAttendance
memberID
eventID
```

To get the full dataset join tblAttendance to tblMember on memberID and to tblEvent on eventID. You could split eventtype out into a separate table, using eventTypeID, if event types are complex enough.